# Schema migrations in Production database?

Tags: python, database, web, database-migration, web-frameworks

I have started learning web development(Flask and Django to be specific), and anywhere I see, the topic of databases always starts with migrations.

From what I've understood for updating databases one should

1. Run a "something to generate migrate script" to generate a migration script which would diff your current models file and the current database.
2. Test the migration script on your local database.
3. Commit the migration script so that it reaches your production environment, wherein run the script again to update your production databases.

But then reading `Schema Migrations` on Wikipedia from this link [Schema Migration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) I came upon the following text:

> schema migration is typically only used when the data held in the
>   database is not real nor valuable, such as in software development,
>   where developers work only with (possibly generated) test
>   data.[citation needed] Programmatic schema migrations are almost never
>   performed in production for the same reason.

It says that one should avoid migrations in prodution, then how are you supposed to update your databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where the author of the Wikipedia article got that idea from; according to the history, it was already in the first revision and for me, this arbitrary limitation doesn't make sense.

Migrating databases alongside with program versions is something that is often necessary and that means it's necessary for production databases. I don't make a distinction here between the data in the rows and the schema since that's a bit arbitrary. From a code point of view, the database is a way to encode data and the encoding scheme directly influences both the schema and the encoding of the data in the rows.

Maybe it would make sense to talk about the risks of such migrations (production databases sometimes contain surprises like corrupt data, data that has been modified by running an SQL query manually) or the complexity (like adding and deleting foreign keys). But I've seen many products which migrate data and schema when a new version is released.

Update: I've updated the Wikipedia page, let's see how long the edit lasts :-)

Comment: It's obvious that the author is referring only to automated schema changes, triggered by a commit or deployment. It's better to edit the wikipedia article to make that explicit, instead of removing the comment. It's not an arbitrary limitation.

Comment: Programatic database migrations happen all the time, i.e. via tools like `south`, `alembic` and `django migrate`. And thats the way it should be, much less potential for errors than with hand coded SQL commands.

Comment: @reptilicus try making a schema migration on a table with billions of rows, on a production database with no native support for online schema changes, using an automated tool like south or alembic, without significant downtime.

Comment: Thats not the question asked. "Programmatic schema migrations are almost never performed in production for the same reason." This is false.

Comment: As for your point, you could still use south/alembic, with the knowledge that it is not going to be possible to perform a live update on a table with 1B rows, this just needs to be taken into account with the developers

Answer (score 3):

I believe what the author means is that **automated** schema migrations should be done only during a development phase, in a development or testing environment, because on a large production database there might be some availability or performance issues during a schema migration.

For instance, in MySQL up to 5.6, there's no native online schema change, so you'll necessarily have a table lock while an `ALTER TABLE` is running. If it's a small table, or a testing environment with generated data, that's usually not a problem -- a small will finish quickly, and you can discard a test table and regenerate data -- but a large table in a production environment might be locked for hours, if not days or weeks, rendering the system unavailable for any interactions involving that table. You have to adopt alternative migration methods to perform the changes with minimum downtime, and they aren't simple or safe to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is absurd. Schema migrations are done all the time to production databases. As needs change, often need to also alter the underlying database. Both Django and Flask have paths to perform database updates, Django's being the built in `mirgrate` command in current versions, and `South` in previous versions. Flask/SQLAlchemy has `alembic` for handling schema changes. That being said, it can still be a pain and can be dangerous, so test test test and have a rollback plan.

Answer (score 0):

Whether automated schema changes are applied via migrations in production or not, is basically a matter of policy of the organization.  Newer organizations with less valuable data and/or smaller databases tend to use these - until they hit a situation where their migrations take a day or longer and might even crash.  If vital data is lost, quite often the policies for database alterations become more conservative and less likely to be driven by developers who wrote the application and more by DBAs or DevOps folk after layers of review.  So IMHO, these statements are a reflection of organizational experience and maturity than absolutes.  In other words it's done until it doesn't work, then some other process is put in place.